# Not inserting data into the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I am trying to create a form that require to retrieve the information about an employee then the employee enter their expenses claim. The process of retrieving data is work correctly, but it is not saving the entered data of expenses claim into the database.

I would be most grateful if anybody could help me.

This is my code.

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['emp_no']){
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['emp_no']."!";
}
 else 
 die("You must enter your employee no. ");

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Omaima2010") or die ("Could not connect");

mysql_select_db("expenses") or die ("Could not find the data base");

$emp_no= $_SESSION['emp_no'];

$query = mysql_query("select e.emp_no, e.manager_no, e.emp_name, m.manager_no, m.manager_name, m.dept_name 
from employee e , manager m
where emp_no = '$emp_no' and e.manager_no = m.manager_no");
while($query1 = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$emp_no = $query1['emp_no'];
$emp_name = $query1 ['emp_name'];
$manager_name = $query1 ['manager_name'];
$manager_no = $query1 ['manager_no'];
$dept_name = $query1 ['dept_name'];
}


    if(isset($_POST['exp_desc'])){

      //This is the directory where vouchers will be saved 
     $target = "vouchers/"; 
     $target = $target .basename( $_FILES['datafile']['name']); 

    $exp_desc = $_POST['exp_desc'];
    $date = (date ("d/m/Y"));
    $receipt = $_FILES['datafile']['name'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $exch_rate= ($_POST['exch_rate']);
    $bd = ($_POST['BD']);

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO expenses_claim(emp_no,manager_no,exp_desc,claimant_date,amount,exch_rate,BD,receipt) VALUES ('$emp_no','$manager_no','$exp_desc','$date','$amount','$exch_rate','$bd','$receipt',now())");

    //Writes the file to the server 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datafile']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
    { 

     //Tells you if its all ok 
     echo "The file " . basename( $_FILES['datafile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 


     } 
     else { 

    //Gives and error if its not 
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
     } 
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 8 columns and 9 values in your query,just delete `,now()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use prepared statements. Also mysql_query is depreciated as of PHP 5.5, so you should switch to mysqli or PDO.
2. Validate your input. I'd wager that your problem is the result of bad input causing the query to fail.
3. If you're sending a query that could fail, make sure to catch your error.  For example:

   ```
   if(!mysql_query($query))
        echo "Your query failed.  It consisted of: $query and the error was " .   mysql_error();
   ```

Comment: I change the code and still does not working, the error that show me:Your query failed. It consisted of: Resource id #4 and the error was Query was empty

Comment: Did you assign your query to the variable $query?

Comment: i.e. $query = "INSERT INTO" etc.

Comment: Well, for whatever reason (I'm not sure, since I haven't seen the revised code) you're not passing a readable string to the query.  Instead, you're passing "Resource id #4" which mysql has no idea how to parse.